# get jsf compoment id in backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have two jsf component like these :

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="cmdtop"

                   disabled="#{ViewDocument.locked or !(documentAttachmentBean.canEditAttachment )}"
                   action="#{documentAttachmentBean.onCmdIncreaseAttachmentCodeClick}"

                   ...


</a4j:commandButton>

<a4j:commandButton id="cmddown"
                   disabled="#{ViewDocument.locked or !(documentAttachmentBean.canEditAttachment )}"
                   action="#{documentAttachmentBean.onCmdDecreaseAttachmentCodeClick}">    
    ...                     

</a4j:commandButton>
```

in my backing bean with canEditAttachment() method I want to check if it has been called for cmdtop or cmddown?
 some thing like this :

```
    public boolean getCanEditAttachment()
{
    if (somecode.getElementId.equals"cmdtop")
 //do something
 return true ;
  else if (somecode.getElementId.equals"cmddown")
  //do something else
   return false ;
```

}

how can I find canEditAttachment() is called with whom ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some global variables in JSF. `component` is one of them. you can access current component that is rendering at the moment with `component` variable.

**xhtml**

```
<h:commandButton id="cmdtop"
                 disabled="#{myBackingBean.canEditAttachment(component.id)}"
                 value="Button 1"/>

<h:commandButton id="cmddown"
                 disabled="#{myBackingBean.canEditAttachment(component.id)}"
                 value="Button 2"/>
```

**java**

```java
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean {

    public boolean canEditAttachment(String componentId) {
        if ("cmdtop".equalsIgnoreCase(componentId))
            return true;
        else if ("cmddown".equalsIgnoreCase(componentId))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works ! but would you please say other global variables ?

Comment: They are named as implicit objects. There is a list at [this blog post](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com.tr/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this only works with JSF 2.0 . JSF 2.0 adds implicit variables to make resolving components easier.

like

> disabled="#{myBackingBean.canEditAttachment(**component.id**)}"

If you are working with outdated legacy code that uses JSF lower than 2.0, this will not work.